# My own css does not override bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I dont know why is my custom css file not overwritting the bootstrap css. I know about the cascade and the fact that my new css class attribute must have higher priority that bootstraps but somehow I am missing the point as how exactly to override it. This is the code:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">`

If I change the `bg_light` to `bg_red` it will change the background to red, but if I try to define it in external cs using only that it won't do anything.

and my css file line is:

```
nav.bg-light {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I have also tried to put all the classes there:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-light {
    background-color: red;
}
```

but it still does not change my color. What am I missing? I am trying to learn how to override the bootstrap css to be able to customize it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your CSS loaded before or after bootstrap?

Comment: Apply with important. Like `background-color: red !important;`

Answer (score 1):

CSS is all about the cascading logic so make sure you load your CSS AFTER you've loaded bootstrap :
ex:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

if the problem continues, then it's most probably because the bootstrap class was defined with an !important property, in this case you should add !important to yours as well

```
nav.bg-light {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank, I have just tried that - ! important works. I have to start inspecting the bootstraps css so next time I know if something is marked ! important there. Thank you all for help

Answer (score 0):

`.bg-light` is a utilitty from Bootstrap to make background color light, and it's property in CSS is defined with `!important`. So, you couldn't override this without too use `!important` in your CSS.

Comment: The properties in bootstrap are marked !Important? I did not know that. So the only way to customise it is always include ! Important after each attribute?  Yes my css is loaded after the bootstrap CDM

Comment: You can inspecionate the element in Bootstrap's docs to see it
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/colors/#background-color

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this will help a lot

Comment: In your case is better remove `.bg-light` from HTML, seems that it is anulated with the style that you are trying to apply

Comment: Right, ok. I have to start looking into bootstraps css to find out what approach to take when changing diffefent attrinutes. Appreciate the help again 